# Two lines in the output with special charachters that shouldn't be there

Tags: c, file, struct

I have a txt with a list of songs in this format:

we will rock you

queen

2:01

and i need to put those data in a list named "elenco" with this struct:

```
struct elenco{
    char titolo[30];
    char autore[30];
    int durata_in_sec;
    int rips;
    struct elenco *prossima;
};
```

I tried to store the datas with `fscanf(fp, "%29[^\n]%*c", elenco->autore);` (and so on) and the output with a simple `printf("%s\n", elenco->autore);` but the output is correct until the program outputs two lines with special characters like this:

> ?w

> ☻ ☻ ☻ ☻ ☻ ☻h☻(☻(☻(☻(☻ ☻ ☻ ☻ ☻y

this is the full program if you want to check it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct elenco{
    char titolo[30];
    char autore[30];
    int durata_in_sec;
    int rips;
    struct elenco *prossima;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("musica.txt", "r");
    int i=0;
    int secondi, minuti;
    struct elenco *start = NULL;
    struct elenco *elenco = NULL;
    struct elenco *prec = NULL;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        elenco = malloc(sizeof(struct elenco));
        fscanf(fp, "%29[^\n]%*c", elenco->titolo);
        fscanf(fp, "%29[^\n]%*c", elenco->autore);
        fscanf(fp, "%d:%d", &minuti, &secondi);
        elenco->durata_in_sec = minuti*60+secondi;
        elenco->rips=1;
        elenco->prossima = NULL;
        if(i==0)
        {
            start = elenco;
        }
        else
        {
            prec->prossima = elenco;
        }
        prec = elenco;
        i++;
    }
    
    // Stampa
    elenco = start;
    while(elenco!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", elenco->titolo);
        printf("%s\n", elenco->autore);
        printf("%d\n", elenco->durata_in_sec);
        printf("%d\n", elenco->rips);
        elenco = elenco->prossima;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    // Free memory
    elenco = start;
    while (elenco != NULL) {
        struct elenco* temp = elenco;
        elenco = elenco->prossima;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the txt

we will rock you
queen
2:01
it's my life
bon jovi
3:46
we will rock you
queen
2:01
the show must go on
queen
4:36

Comment: You should terminate c-strings with a null byte `\0`. The extra data is printed because you are not adding this after scanning the input data and you never initialized the char arrays. It would be a good practice to initialize your char arrays to all null bytes, then only write up to the first 29 bytes (leaving the final byte for the null byte).

Comment: Please don't double-space code. It's quite hard to read.

Comment: `feof()` won't work as you need to check for errors on each i/o operation.

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You need to check the return value of each `fscanf()` otherwise you may be operating on unitialized data.

Comment: If you add a space before `%29[^\n]` it will consume the leading whitespace left by the last `%d` and also eliminate the need for the trailing  `%*c`. So `fscanf(fp, " %29[^\n]", elenco->titolo);` and the same for the next line.  If you check the return value from `fscanf` you can tell when it failed to convert the correct number of arguments. `while (!feof(fp))` is also generally a bad idea.

Comment: Another point: stop trying to kludge away newlines with `fscanf(fp, "%29[^\n]%*c", elenco->titolo);` You don't do that with other format specs such as `%d` which also leave the newline in the buffer. Use `fscanf(fp, " %29[^\n]", elenco->titolo);` with a space before the `%`. With `%c` and `%[]` you must specify if you want leading whitespace removed, which is usually automatic.

Comment: writing fscanf(fp, " %29[^\n]", elenco->titolo); solve the problem! Now i need to understand how should i change while(!feof(fp))

Comment: i don't understand how that space before %29 can solve the problem, i'm so curious

Comment: One way is to use the return value from `fscanf` which you *must* **always** check *anyway*. Such as `while(fscanf(....) == N)` where you replace N with the number of arguments you expect to be converted.

Comment: Re "that space". Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too. The reason is those three specifiers allow you to read every character including whitespace, but a way is provided so they behave like `%d` and `%f` and `%s` (etc) where needed.

Comment: what if uses a while(scanf(fp, " %29[^\n]", elenco->titolo)==1) instead of the while(!feof(fp))?

Comment: Isn't that what was suggested? But you still need to check the return value from all the other `fscanf` use too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use symbolic constants instead of magic numbers.
2. Prefer initialized variables.
3. Remove unused variables. `i` is only used to determine if `start` has been set so might as well eliminate it, too.
4. Check return value from `fopen()`.
5. Use the `str()` macro to let the compiler generate your maximum field width.
6. " %[^\n]" is usually more readable than "%[^\n]%*c".  The former ignores leading white space, while the latter ignores exactly one trailing character.
7. `while(!feof())` doesn't work.  In this case you can read the whole record with a single `fscanf()` call.  This also gives you one place to check for invalid input / `EOF`.
8. Check return value from `malloc()`.
9. As you pre-allocate each record you need to free the last one.
10. Ensure your strings are '\0' terminated.
11. `fclose()` file as soon as you are done.
12. Minimize scope of variables.  This makes your code easier to reason about.
13. Prefer `for`-loops for iteration.
14. (Not fixed) Consider breaking your code into smaller functions (`elenco_load()`, `elenco_print()`, `elenco_free()`).  It makes it easier to reason about and test.
15. (Not fixed) Consider using more specific types.  Do you want to allow negative `durata_in_sec`?  Do you expect duration of `INT_MAX` or would a smaller type do?  Is `secondi < 0 || secondi >= 60` valid input (`unsigned char`)?
16. (Not fixed) As you hard-code `rips=1` consider eliminating it from `struct elenco` in favor of a symbolic constant `#define RIPS 1`.  When printing you now just do `print("%d\n", RIPS).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TITOLO_LEN 29
#define AUTORE_LEN 29
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

struct elenco {
    char titolo[TITOLO_LEN+1];
    char autore[AUTORE_LEN+1];
    int durata_in_sec;
    int rips;
    struct elenco *prossima;
};

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("musica.txt", "r");
    if(!fp) {
        printf("fopen failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct elenco *start = NULL;
    for(struct elenco *prec = NULL;;) {
        struct elenco *elenco = malloc(sizeof *elenco);
        if(!elenco) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        int secondi, minuti;
        int rv = fscanf(fp,
            " %" str(TITOLO_LEN) "[^\n]"
            " %" str(AUTORE_LEN) "[^\n]"
            " %d:%d",
            elenco->titolo,
            elenco->autore,
            &minuti,
            &secondi
        );
        if(rv != 4) {
            free(elenco);
            if(prec)
                prec->prossima = NULL;
            break;
        }
        elenco->durata_in_sec = minuti*60+secondi;
        elenco->rips=1;
        if(!start)
            start = elenco;
        else
            prec->prossima = elenco;
        prec = elenco;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // Stampa
    for(struct elenco *elenco = start; elenco; elenco = elenco->prossima) {
        printf("%s\n", elenco->titolo);
        printf("%s\n", elenco->autore);
        printf("%d\n", elenco->durata_in_sec);
        printf("%d\n", elenco->rips);
    }

    // Free memory
    for(struct elenco *elenco = start; elenco;) {
        struct elenco* temp = elenco;
        elenco = elenco->prossima;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and example run:

```
we will rock you
queen
121
1
it's my life
bon jovi
226
1
we will rock you
queen
121
1
the show must go on
queen
276
1
```

Comment: i don't understand a lot how that for loop works, i was thinking to adjust instead of while(!feof(fp)) to add while(fscanf(fp, " %29[\n]", elenco->autore)==1 && ... ) and so on for every element of the struct

Comment: `for(a; b; c) ...` is the same as { a; while(b) { ...; c } }`.  You certainly can write a bunch of code in your while expression but it's hard to read.

Comment: Or doing the loop with while(1) and then check everytime i use fscanf if !=1 (or 2 when i take minuti and secondi) i use free(elenco); and then break;

Comment: Yeah; that's better `while(1)` is longer to write than `for(;;)` so I usually use the latter.  In this case my answer also limits the scope of `prec` variable.  To get that effect you would need to do: `{struct elenco *prec = NULL; while(1) { ... }}`.  The latter loops makes it clear that `elenco` is not a dependency between the 3 parts of your code.

Comment: ok, i have changed this part in this way: while (!feof(fp))
    {
        elenco = malloc(sizeof(struct elenco));
        if(!elenco)
        {
            printf("malloc fallito\n");
            return 1;
        }
        fscanf(fp, " %29[^\n]", elenco->titolo);
        fscanf(fp, " %29[^\n]", elenco->autore);
        fscanf(fp, " %d:%d", &minuti, &secondi);
        elenco->titolo[29] = '\0';
        elenco->autore[29] = '\0'; ... now i need to understand how you managed the for loop, and how you used start, elenco and prec because you changed it too

Comment: i need rips because i will need to add a part to check repetition on if the song has been listened 2 or more times, that part will be done after i have done a good job on the build itself

Comment: @AllanWind, Good use of `str()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, I will changed as suggested. My thinking was op might want an error message if a field is missing but not if `EOF`.  Not sure where `rv == 0` falls without running some tests.  I obviously remembered wrong, `strncpy()` is the limbo terminator.